# How do you handle <track>, if video doesn't have any audio at all?

Tags: html, accessibility

I bumped into the following a11y error, when I am using `<video>`:

```
A11y: <video> elements must have a <track kind="captions">
```

But the video I have there doesn't have any audio. I am using that as a gif alternative, as it is much smaller in size. As the `<track>` is used for describing the audio, how should I handle this warning?

Comment: There is probably an elegant way to handle this, but I think it begs the question: is there any reason you can’t just ignore it knowing the specifics of your context?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the error. Make sure there's a description of the video for the visually impaired, however.

That's what the [W3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/act/rules/c3232f/proposed/) does in one of its "passed" examples:

> This video element, which has no audio, has a text transcript available on the same page. Thus, it passes rule [Video Element Visual-Only Content Has Transcript](https://act-rules.github.io/rules/ee13b5).
>
> > 

```html
<html lang="en">
<video controls>
  <source src="/test-assets/rabbit-video/silent.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  <source src="/test-assets/rabbit-video/silent.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
</video>
<p>The above video shows a giant fat rabbit climbing out of a hole in the ground.
He stretches, yawns, and then starts walking.
Then he stops to scratch his bottom.</p>
</html>
```